# Log Parser Studio: Counts of 500 errors and non-errors by month

Tags: logparser

Parsing w3c logs, I want to get the count of 500 errors and not for each month.
This gives the count of 500s per month:

```
SELECT TO_STRING(date, 'yyyy-MM') AS yearMonth, COUNT(*) AS HowMany
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%pageIcareabout%'
AND sc-status = 500
GROUP BY yearMonth
```

Changing `sc-status = 500` to `sc-status <> 500` gives the count of not-500s.
However, I don't know how to show both 500s and not-500s, as separate columns for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
SELECT 
      TO_STRING(date, 'yyyy-MM') AS yearMonth 
    , SUM(500) AS 500s
    , SUM(Not500) AS Not500s
USING 
      CASE sc-status WHEN 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 500
    , CASE sc-status WHEN 500 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Not500
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%pageIcareabout%'
GROUP BY yearMonth
```

Result is just what I wanted -- 3 columns, yearMonth, 500s, and Not500s, the last 2 being the count of their respective values for the month.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to use the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT TO_STRING(date, 'yyyy-MM') AS yearMonth, MyStatus, COUNT(*) AS HowMany
USING CASE sc-status WHEN 500 THEN '500' ELSE 'Not500' END AS MyStatus
FROM ...
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%pageIcareabout%'
GROUP BY yearMonth, MyStatus
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. a) it's missing the FROM clause, b) It gives the error 'Unknown field "500", c) If I'm not mistaken, if it had worked, there would be 2 rows for each month, one with the count of 500s and one with count of not-500s, where I was looking for a single row per month, with both counts, as in my answer.

Comment: Well, it was meant to be an example on how to use the `CASE` statement. I've added a `FROM` clause to it works out of the box.